# Sqlite not in list of Visual Studio data source options

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite

Downloaded and ran SQLite setup.
Added dll reference to my project
In Server Explorer, added new connection, clicked 'Change' for data source and SQLite was one of the options.
Connected and used my tables.

Then...VS 2010 crashed.
When I reloaded my project, my connection wasn't in Server explorer, so tried to add it again.
SQLite was not in the list of options.
Re-ran SQLite setup, deleted/re-added reference, restarted project...still no SQLite in the list.

How can I get SQLite connected in Server Explorer???

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question but for someone, like me, who finds this before there is a newer answer:

[missing SQLite data provider in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665370/missing-sqlite-data-provider-in-vs-2013)

Basically for the latest versions of SQLite you can download an installer that includes the components

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Choose the right setup for you, for me was:
Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1) 
sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0.exe

Comment: Notice: if you use 64 system and didn't work, then install 32 version

Comment: I came here because I was not getting the option for System.Data.SQLite Database File in the Data Source menu in VS 2015. The solution was to install:  
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.103.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.103.0.exe

Answer (score 7):

I have Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio community 2015 and this solution worked for me.
Basically you need install SQLite bundel and check the "Install the designer component for Visual Studio 2015".
If you have different version from 2015 (2010/2013 etc.) just search for the bundle the suits your version.

**1. Go to:**
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

**2. Download** "sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.104.0" (download the most updated, this is the one I found).

[image]

Or by a direct link:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.104.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.104.0.exe

**3. Run the setup:**
[image]
[image]

**4. Result:**
[image]

Comment: I installed "sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.113.0.exe" and it is not working on VS2019.

Comment: Did you have all the steps I had?

Comment: Following the steps from https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider is straight forward. Only issue is that we have to enter an absolute path, can we enter a relative path instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can find installers on the [System.Data.SQLite Dowload Page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). Seteps files will suit your needs.

For example, the description of the *Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)* states:

> This setup package features the mixed-mode assembly and will install all the necessary runtime components and dependencies for the x64 version of the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.81.0 (3.7.12.1) package. The Visual C++ 2010 SP1 runtime for x64 is included. The .NET Framework 4.0 is required.

Answer (score 0):

None of answers worked for me. in addition to @E235 answer 
i added sqlite nuget package 
updated ef to 6.1.3
then it worked i was able to see datasource