# missing SQLite data provider in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, dataprovider

I'm using VS 2013 to develop Win 8.1 app. I chose to deal with SQLite but I coudn't find the data provider when I was trying to add a new connection to manage my database.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would like to add something to JDL answer : as my windows is x64, I've installed the related version (sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.94.0) and it didn't work : no new connector in VS. As VS is 32 bits application, I was wondering if it could be related. So I tried the x86 one and got my answer, it was now ok : even on a x64 system, the version to install to enable VS designer support is the x86. Good to know !!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Install this:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe
and reboot evertything

I have lost 3 hours with this problem

Updated with new version.
Updated with sanuel-jackson's comment info.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but I checked the box "Install the designer components for Visual Studio 2013" and it worked for me.

Comment: installed, rebooted, still can't seem to get vs2013 to show it in new item or connections dialog..

Comment: As my windows is x64, I've installed the related version (sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.94.0) and it didn't work : no new connector in VS. As VS is 32 bits application, I was wondering if it could be related. So I tried the x86 one and got my answer, it was now ok : even on a x64 system, the version to install to enable VS designer support is the x86. Good to know !!

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't always work. I've got a Win 8.1 64-bit machine with VS 2013. Running this link or the latest 1.0.96.0 link DOES NOT add the SQLite provider to the provider list when trying to connect via Server Explorer.

Comment: Current version as of writing this is located here >> http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.98.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.98.0.exe

Comment: Couldn't get any of these Sqlite installations to reveal the tools in 64 bit win 7 VS2015

Comment: Whoops, It actually just appeared!... removing the old references in the App.config file and reinstalling the NuGet packages helped I think ... Also for me it only shows when you select: Server Explorer > Data Connections > xxxxxx.mdf > (right click) Modify Connection > Change

Comment: I added explained solution for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215488/sqlite-not-in-list-of-visual-studio-data-source-options/41766336#41766336

Answer (score 11):

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

and download Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1) where 
**This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2013.**