# Can't install ADO.NET provider for sqlite in VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

after reading this article [missing SQLite data provider in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665370/missing-sqlite-data-provider-in-vs-2013) , I've tried to register SQLITE provider for VS 2013 installing the specific provider with ddex included but with no result.
When I reboot VS 2013 I can't find it in the list of ADO.NET provider and I can't create the Model for my sqlite DB.
Managing app.config of my application I was able to load dinamically the provider but this is not a good choice for my developer's team.

I've also tried to install SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox for VS but now I can see only SQLCE provider and not Sqlite.

Searching DATAPROVIDER in windows registry i've seen that the Sqlite provider and SQLCE provider were installed in two different ways, infact under supported object for SQLCE data provider I can find many reference to Visual Studio(ex: IVsDataAsyncCommand) , while under Supported object of SQLite provider I can see any reference to Visual studio.
In my opinion the problem is here.

Is there a simple way to register DDEX SQLite provider on VS 2013 in windows registry or any other type of operation to do to register this provider definitively?

Thanks in advance,

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

you go to the page of [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) download page.

You have to download and install the correct BUNDLE package, depends on your framework and VS version.

Assuming framework 4.5.1 you have to download
sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0.exe

This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I 've just visit that page and just tried to install this package but with no result. The data provider was correctly installed on VS 2013 but designer wasn't (DDEX component).

Comment: @zewale have you installed ibm client access on your machine?

Comment: No, I haven't. I've seen that there are other provider for SQLite but System.Data.Sqlite is free and support Entity Framework. I think that it is the unique with this two interesting features.

Comment: during the installation process have you checked the checkboxes "install the design time component"?

Comment: Yes, I have. Installation of data provider take few minutes and not few second as I would expect.

Comment: check your machine.config file under c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\config in the section provider factories if the provider is registered.

Comment: Yes, in machine.config file under framework\config the provider is registered. Under framework64\onfig the provider is not registered but Visual studio is a 32 bit application, so in my opinion it is correct.