# VS 2015 SQLite data provider

Tags: sqlite, dataprovider, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015 and i want to develop Win Form application with .NET Framework 4.5 and SQLite.

I have install the last "System.Data.SQLite" nuget package with all dependencies to my project but I couldn't find the SQLite data provider when I was trying to add a new connection to manage my database.

I try the solution for VS 2013 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665370/missing-sqlite-data-provider-in-vs-2013) but don't works.

there is still no bundle for VS 2015, this is the problem?
is any solution to use 2013 bundle in 2015, or other solutions?

Answer (score 12):

Installing this package:
*sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.103.0.exe* should fix that.
You need specifically 32-bit version

From http://system.data.sqlite.org/:

> This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the
>   design-time components for Visual Studio 2015.

This is working link at the time of writing
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.103.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.103.0.exe

will add sqlite to the server explorer in VS2015

Comment: Does this work on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to install [this package](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe).

You have to check the second checkbox that will integrate SQLite into Visual Studio 2015 in the installation wizard.

The package Daniel showed us didn't work for me.

My configuration is this: VS 2015, from Nuget I installed Entity Framework 6, System.Data.SQLite.Core version 1.0.101, project is in .Net 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Install the sqlite-net nuget into your solution

Comment: doing that it gave me an error about MSBuild version. I had to install EF6 first and then Sqlite, then it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the development of sqlLite data provider for ef 7 has been actually suspended.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/12/02/ef7-priorities-focus-and-initial-release.aspx
if you want to use it you have just to wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution to import from 2013 with the provider using a connection string in the parameters.
And when you open it with 2015 it works but you can not change the provider options.
If you want to change the .db you must use a sqlite browser.

Sorry for my english.I hope you have understood
cya

Answer (score 0):

You old application from VS 2013 and sqlite will work but you can not connect to new database or edit EF model until Sqlite publish design-time components for Visual Studio 2015.