# SQLite database first with entity framework in VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, ef-database-first

I want to create WPF application that will use SQLite database with Entity framework. 
I googled and found these [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330352/generating-sqlite-database-from-model-at-vs-2015-ef7), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507904/vs-2015-sqlite-data-provider), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0) that says i need to install [sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.99.0.exe](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.99.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.99.0.exe). Now when i am trying to connect to Database i am getting following error.
[image: SQLite Error]

I googled but could not find any solutions. Please help to solve this error.

Comment: What code are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: I haven't wrote a single code. What i did is 
1) Created New WPF Poject
2)Added NuGet packages of Entity Framework then added SQLite packages.
3)Tools>>Connect To Database>>Select SQLite DB
When i click "ok" i am facing that error.

Comment: @Gilgamesh am i doing anything wrong or skipped any step?

Answer (score 0):

I Had this exact issue, Mine was cause by having an older version previously installed In :

"C:\Program Files (x86)\System.Data.SQLite\2010"

Uninstalling this and then deleting the directory, followed by reinstalling the newer 2015 version Fixed it, Hope this helps
 Link below is from where i found my solution

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/8b77722ff3b0e766fce4db053f3a62d09af942e7