# VS2015 CE SQLite - How to create a typed DataSet

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I read a manual how to create a typed DataSet under VS2015 CE with the common Database driver (MySQL, MS Access/ODBC/Server/Server-Database).

To archive this: 
**View -> Server-Explorer -> Connect to Database -> Change -> select driver -> provide the necessary information** But this doesn't work for SQLite. I already installed https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1 and tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749302/6635287

After rebooting there was no entry for a **SQLite** in the dialoge after **Change**. Just two **SQL Server Compact** entries (the first was version 3.5, the second 4.0

In the Server Explorer appeard a new symbol (two blue symbolic databases). When clicking on them, a dialog appears, which offers me a treeview, containing "Data Connections" as root element having one child. After right-clicking the root element I get a context menue with some options:

- Add SQL Server Compact 4.0 Connection...
- Add SQL Server Compact 3.5 Connection... (out-grayed)
- Add SQLite Connection...
- ...

I was already able to make a connection to the SQLite File but when creating a typed DataSet, I can't access to the SQLite connection.

Does anyone know a way to archiev this (creating a typed DataSet with SQLite)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the System.Data.SQLite NuGet pagage via the NuGet package manager. After installation there is a new type of connection: **System.Data.SQLite Database File**. Create a new connection to the SQLite file