# SQLite update version on c# project

Tags: c#, sqlite, version-control

In an old project (Visualstudio 2015 .net 4.5 ) I used sqlite 1.0.99.

Last mount I have update SQLite on my pc at the version 1.0.109.

Now, when I open any form of the project visual studio show this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. Impossibile trovare il file specificato

I have update the dll on the reference but the error show anyway.

what solution of my problem?

Comment: I suggest to use a texteditor to look into every csproj for the SQLite reference and look at the version required

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you updated SQLite in all projects - even if they only hold a reference to projects/libs containing your actual SQLite-project.

Comment: The project have a only one csproj files and it's correctly configured with 1.0.103 version.
If I build the project, the build succeded correctly.
If I open a form in design mode the error show.

I'm really confused!

Comment: have you tried a clean+rebuild? from my experience the usage of System.Data.SQLite is usually hassle-free - besides the mentioned fact that every project referencing a SQLite-csproj or dll needs to have its own reference to System.Data.Sqlite.dll

Comment: I think that the problem is the incompatibility between VisualStudio and design component of sqlite version 1.0.103.
Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507904/vs-2015-sqlite-data-provider