# missing SQLite data provider in VS 2015

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

can you tell me how to add SQLite to VS 2015.

[image]

I already installed : http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe
without any success.
can you help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665370/missing-sqlite-data-provider-in-vs-2013?

Comment: thanks for you answer, Nimesch yes and I installed http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe but no solution

Comment: Is your OS 32 bit or 64 bit? and what edition of VS 2015?

Comment: 64, I have express version.

Comment: Tested this on Community edition that I've installed. No issues. Check the below answer for the sources leading to conclusion that it's just because of Express edition. Are you able to connect to the database using code i.e. using *connection string*?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the Visual Studio is Express Edition:

As per the Readme file provided with setup.

> Visual Studio design-time Support, works with all versions of Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010/2012/2013/2015. You can add a SQLite database to the Servers list, design queries with the Query Designer, drag-and-drop tables onto a Typed DataSet, etc.
> **Due to Visual Studio licensing restrictions, the Express Editions can no longer be supported.**

As per the [website FAQ](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q4):

> **What versions of Visual Studio are supported?**
>
> *Currently, Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 are supported, including the "Express" editions*; however, in order to build the entire solution, including the necessary native code, the "Professional" edition (or higher) is required. It may be possible to install both Visual C# Express and Visual C++ Express and then build the corresponding sub-projects via their respective integrated development environments (IDE); however, this configuration has not been tested. **The design-time components are no longer supported for the Express editions due to licensing restrictions.**

Comment: Hi Nimesh, thanks for the answer, just for info I have the VS 2013 comunity too.I can connect my app to sqlite, but I want to generate a dataset of my SQlitedatabase to use Datagridview und update my database easely buy draguing it on the form, but now I can't do it.

Comment: So you are saying that you've Community 2013 and Express 2015 and it's not working in both the versions? Did you tried reinstalling the setup?

Comment: I also see the suggestion of installing nuget package `sqlite-net` into the solution on other questions. Did you try that?

Comment: No I'm gonna do it and see if there is any difference

Comment: Hi Nimesh, I just did but in vain