# Visual Studio 2015 Windows Application Form with SQLite

Tags: visual-studio-2015, system.data.sqlite, .net-4.6

I need to create an application which needs to access basic data in a database in a simple way. So I decided to use SQLite as a database manager and Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 in order to achieve my goal.

My first step was to look for some info related to link a database created in SQLite with a Visual Studio Windows Application Form. I found this very simple and easy to follow YouTube playlist named [C# & SQLite](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiNd7TUPozDET_shXjcaYQiXscVDGIZkU). Everything was fine until I had to create a new element named ADO.NET Entity Data Model which creates a model from an existing database. EF Designer to be precise. The problem is I can't "see" the existing database.

This is odd because I can work with the database through VS2015 using an extension named SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox. Right now I have this features installed:

SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox:
[image: Toolbox]

My NuGet packages:
[image: NuGet packages]

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6 as you could see below:
[image: .NET Framework version]

The references in my project:
[image: References]

The second video of the previous mentioned playlist indicates to download an executable from the [system.data.sqlite web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749568/missing-ado-net-data-source-for-sqlite-in-visual-studio-2015). I have it installed too for .NET Framework 4.6 (the first one because I'm using x64):

[image: system.data.sqlite executable]

This is the problem I'm getting, no database is listed.
[image: No database found]

Why is this happening? I am even able to modify the database through Visual Studio.

---

Similar issues if interested:

- [How to connect to Sqlite in Visual Studio and create database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863371/how-to-connect-to-sqlite-in-visual-studio-and-create-database?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Sqlite not in list of Visual Studio data source options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215488/sqlite-not-in-list-of-visual-studio-data-source-options?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Missing ADO.NET data source for sqlite in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749568/missing-ado-net-data-source-for-sqlite-in-visual-studio-2015)